# How to test complete IntegrationFlow from MessagingGateway to ServiceActivator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, junit5, spring-integration-dsl

In our Spring Boot project we have the following IntegrationFlow configuration

```java
package our.configs;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class MessageChannelsConfiguration {
    public static final String OUTBOUND_CHANNEL = "outboundChannel";
    public static final String OUTBOUND_CHANNEL_GROUP_ID = "outboundMessageGroup";

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow outboundSnapshotMessageChannel(ChannelMessageStore outboundChannelMessageStore,
                                                   OutboundFixMessageService outboundMessageService) {
        return f -> f
                .channel(c -> c.queue(
                        OUTBOUND_CHANNEL,
                        outboundChannelMessageStore,
                        OUTBOUND_CHANNEL_GROUP_ID))
                .handle(outboundMessageService, "processOutboundMessage");
    }

    @Bean
    OutboundMessageService outboundFixMessageService(ObjectMapper objectMapper){
        return new OutboundMessageService(objectMapper);
    }

    @Bean
    ChannelMessageStore outboundChannelMessageStore(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource,
                                                    ChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider channelMessageStoreQueryProvider) {
        JdbcChannelMessageStore jdbcChannelMessageStore = new JdbcChannelMessageStore(dataSource);
        jdbcChannelMessageStore.setChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider(channelMessageStoreQueryProvider);
        jdbcChannelMessageStore.setRegion("TX_TIMEOUT");
        return jdbcChannelMessageStore;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile({"test"})
    ChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider jdbcChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider() {
        return new H2ChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider();
    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata poller(TransactionManager transactionManager,
                                 Initiator clientInitiator) {
        return Pollers.fixedRate(500))
                .maxMessagesPerPoll(1)
                .advice(transactionInterceptor(transactionManager), new CheckSessionPollingAdvise(clientInitiator))
                .get();
    }

    private TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor(TransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new TransactionInterceptorBuilder()
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .propagation(Propagation.NESTED)
                .build();
    }
}
```

and the messaging Gateway which is defined as in a separate package then the above configuration

```java
package our.businesslogic;

@MessagingGateway
public interface OutboundMessageGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = MessageChannelsConfiguration.OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)
    void sendMarkerMessage(Object markerMessage,
                           @Header(ChannelMessageHeaders.RECIPIENT_ID) String institutionId,
                           @Header(ChannelMessageHeaders.MESSAGE_TYPE) ChannelMessageType channelMessageType);


    @Gateway(requestChannel = MessageChannelsConfiguration.OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)
    void sendOrderMessage(Order message,
                                 @Header(ChannelMessageHeaders.RECIPIENT_ID) String institutionId,
                                 @Header(ChannelMessageHeaders.MESSAGE_TYPE) ChannelMessageType channelMessageType);

}
```

I want to test the behavior of the complete flow including the persistence to the `JdbcChannelMessageStore` (and later also the transactional scenarios) with `JUnit5`.

E.g.

```java
    @Test
    void whenSendTrancheMessage_givenPollingBlockedByAdvise_thenCorrectNumberOfMessagesOnQueue() {
        //given
        String recipientId = "Mocked-recipient";
        List<Order> orders = Arrays.asList(
                new Order(),
                new Order(),
                new Order(),
                new Order()
        );

        //when
        clientInitiator.stopConnection(); // Queue will not be read as long as 
                                          // there is no connection 

        orders.forEach(order->
                outboundMessageGateway.sendOrderMessage(order,recipientId,ChannelMessageType.SNAPSHOT));
        //then
        Assertions.assertThat(outboundChannelMessageStore.messageGroupSize(FixMessageChannelsConfiguration.OUTBOUND_CHANNEL_GROUP_ID))
                .isEqualTo(orders.size());
    }

    @Test
    void whenSendTrancheMessage_givenPollingIsNotBlocked_thenMessagesAreReceivedByHandler() {
          //some test code with mocked ServiceActivator
     }
```

I have tried with two different ways

1. as an Integration test with `@SpringBootTest`
2. as a context specific JUnit test with `@ContextConfiguration` and `@SpringIntegrationTest`

In case of 1) my tests are working when called separately, but are failing with the following exception when they are run together with existing integration tests

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class p
ath resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation vi
a factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servl
et.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnection
Exception: Exception opening port "9092" (port may be in use), cause: "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind" [900
61-199]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowir
eCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
```

In case of 2) the following exception is thrown showing problems with the `outboundMessageGateway`

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
... ... ... 
       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'outboundMessageGateway': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [our.businesslogic.OutboundMessageGateway]: Specified class is an interface
```

I would appreciate it very much if someone could help me to solve this issues.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception opening port "9092"

You probably need to add a `@DirtiesContext` along side with the mentioned `@SpringBootTest`.

> Failed to instantiate [our.businesslogic.OutboundMessageGateway]

If you don't use Spring Boot in your test environment, you must be explicit `@EnableIntegration` and `@IntegrationComponentScan` must be there to Spring Integration infrastructure available.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#configuration-enable-integration

> ```
> Assertions.assertThat(outboundChannelMessageStore.messageGroupSize(FixMessageChannelsConfiguration.OUTBOUND_CHANNEL_GROUP_ID))
>            .isEqualTo(orders.size());
> ```

You can't check this if your `handle(outboundMessageService, "processOutboundMessage")` is not stopped. Since you have a poller for the queue channel, it is going to pull all the message from the store and lets that handler to process them. So, there is going to be nothing in the store at the moment you try to verify it (or some wrong unexpected number).

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks again for your detailed reply. In the example test, queue polling is blocked by the `CheckSessionPollingAdvise`. 
Added the following line to the test
`clientInitiator.stopConnection(); // Queue will not be read as long as here is no connection`
Will try out your other suggestions and will write later.

Comment: So, how then `outboundChannelMessageStore.messageGroupSize()` is going to work since there is no connection? You need to think to have your `handle(outboundMessageService, "processOutboundMessage")` stopped to not poll message from the store by that queue channel.

Comment: The poller advice `advice(transactionInterceptor(transactionManager), new CheckSessionPollingAdvise(clientInitiator))` does exactly this. It checks if the connection to an external consumer service is up. If not, then polling is stopped

Comment: OK. So, what the problem do you have at the moment then?

Comment: So, what the problem do you have at the moment? That was almost month ago we've been here, so, I'm lost a bit...

Comment: Sorry, clearing the profiles or setting `@DirtiesContext ` did not work for the same error `Exception opening port "9092" (port may be in use)`. Could this be a bug in `spring-integration-jdbc`?

Comment: No, Spring Integration doesn't start database. See here if you use Spring Boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jdbc-test

Comment: Also see here: https://david-kerwick.github.io/2017-02-23-setting-up-h2-with-spring-boot/. Pay attention to the `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT`.

Comment: The only solution or workaround for now is to use dedicated `h2` databases for the different test classes:
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:itestdb;Mode=Oracle
 web.security.tcpPort=9092` 
and 
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:fixtestdb;Mode=Oracle
web.security.tcpPort=9091`

Comment: Probably it would be better to find a way how all test could share a single embedded data base instance, but for now the above solution is a way forward